# django modelForm, need to save only selected fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

how can i save only selected field in my modelForm? Documentation doesn't help me
my form:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
       fields = ['avatar', 'firstname', 'lastname',
            'date_of_birth',]

        widgets = {
        'date_of_birth': SelectDateWidget(years=range(1920, 2015)),
        }
```

my view:

```
def cabinet(request):

    profile_user = CustomUser.objects.filter(pk = request.user.pk)
    profile = CustomUser.objects.get(pk = request.user.pk)
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)

    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.profile_user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
        obj.save()
        return redirect(reverse(cabinet))

    return render(request, 'cabinet.html', 
    {'form':form, 'profile_user': profile_user,}, )
```

in html code it's just:

```
        <form action="{% url 'cabinet' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

So, if I want only change my 'name' field, i save other fields by empty values.

And other problem here, at the top of my avatar field i have this:
[image]

Documentation doesn't help for both of this problems

UPD  My form view:
[image]

UPD my CustomUser model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', message='Only                     alphanumeric characters are allowed.')

    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30, validators=[alphanumeric])

    email = models.EmailField(
    'Email',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
    db_index=True
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(
    'Avatar',
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    upload_to='user/avatar',
    default='user/default.jpg'
    )
    firstname = models.CharField(
    'First name',
    max_length=40,
    blank=True,
    null=True
    )
    lastname = models.CharField(
    'Last name',
    max_length=40,
    blank=True,
    null=True
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(
    'Date of birth',
    blank=True,
    null=True
    )
    register_date = models.DateField(
    'Register date',
    auto_now_add=True
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
    'Active',
    default=True
    )
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(
    'Superuser',
    default=False
    )

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
```

Comment: Why are you including the other fields in the form if you don't want to save them?

Comment: oh, all I need to create single form for single field. I'm right?   upd: I tried, it doesn't works

Comment: Any field included on the form will be saved.  But also, any field included on the form should be displayed.. and if you don't change it.. it shouldn't matter....  So, are all your fields eg "date_of_birth" etc being displayed correctly?  If not, then something odd is going on.

Comment: Also, why are you storing a reference to the profile in itself (assigning CustomUser instance to the profile_user column of the identical CustomUser record)???

Comment: i'm going to update my question, with picture of my form. I want to display all model fields, and save only changed field, i mean, if form is empty, it wouldnt save empty value. And i need to now, what should i fix, my form, view, template form or all of this stuff, sorry if I explain unclear

Comment: @little_birdie , 'profile_user' it is request.user, i paste my code incorectly.

Comment: Could you add your CustomUser model code?

Comment: Done. I update question. You dont need manager for CustomUser model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this finally. No need to changhe save() method.
Here the changes:

```
def cabinet(request):

    profile_user = CustomUser.objects.filter(pk = request.user.pk)
    profile = CustomUser.objects.get(pk = request.user.pk)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None,     instance=profile)   
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)

    return render(request, 'cabinet.html', 
    {'form':form, 'profile_user': profile_user, 'rating':rating,}, )
```

But I still have problem with avatar widget

Answer (score 3):

You just need to remove the additional fields from the `cleaned_data` before you save it.

Override the `save` method, and remove them from there an it should work fine.

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # skip initial details

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.cleaned_data = dict([ (k,v) for k,v in self.cleaned_data.items() if v != "" ])
        return super(ProfileForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

Comment: sorry I misunderstanding a bit, where i should delete fields?

Comment: You shouldn't delete any fields you want the user to have an option of editing, this just prevents blank fields from being saved.

Comment: so, i just paste your "save" method in my model form? But it doesn't worked, form still saving empty fields.   Or  I need to change fields in my CustomUser model?